# Is there a supervised/semi supervised version of pca for dimensionality reduction?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction, svd

PCA can give me the proper result if "Large variances have important dynamics" holds true for the data. In other words if I want to know along which components the variance of my data is maximized, pca can provide me just that. So according to pca, the very first component is the one where most of variance of data is reflected

From [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat505/node/54) link, I got a table where correlation of first 3 principle components with original 9 dimensions is showed.

```
Variable      Principal Component

                    1        2        3

Climate          0.190      0.017     0.207

Housing         *0.544*     0.020     0.204

Health          *0.782*   *-0.605*    0.144

Crime            0.365      0.294    *0.585*

Transportation  *0.585*     0.085     0.234

Education        0.394     -0.273     0.027

Arts            *0.985*     0.126    -0.111

Recreation      *0.520*     0.402    *0.519*

Economy          0.142      0.150     0.239
```

Here as we can see, The first principal component increases with increasing Arts, Health, Transportation, Housing and Recreation scores. And this is the component where most of the variance of data is observed.

My question is if I want to find out such a component which will give me most of the variance of some dimensions of data but not as whole, how can I do that?

More specifically, using this example I want to find such a component which has strong correlation with Housing Health **Crime** & Transportation (instead of Arts, Health, Transportation, Housing and Recreation), and other components give the best possible variance after fulfilling first condition, how can I do that?

For example my priority can be: treat Health, Transportation, Housing and **Crime** as a label and get as much as variance of these in the first component and get the 2nd best on second one and so on.
This may look like :

```
Variable      Principal Component

                    1        2        3

Climate          0.290      0.017     0.207

Housing         *0.444*     0.020     0.204

Health          *0.482*    -*0.405*     0.144

Crime           *0.465*     0.394     0.435

Transportation  *0.485*     0.085     0.234

Education        0.394     -0.273     0.027

Arts            *0.685*     0.426    -0.111

Recreation       0.350      0.402    *0.419*

Economy          0.242      0.150     0.239
```

Comment: `Housing Health Crime & Transportation` Why wouldn't you perform PCA on this subset of "dimensions" only?

Comment: Can you clarify the first sentence of this question? It is incredibly vague.

Comment: If I perform PCA on this subset then among the top 2 principal components, Housing, Health & Transportation will be strongly correlated with 1st one, and crime will be correlated with second one. 
This will happen because pca will try get as much variance as possible in the 1st component. I want somewhat supervised version of pca that will provide me the following along with remaining best possible result of other dimensions:
Housing          0.444     0.020     0.204
Health           0.482   -0.305    0.144
Crime            0.465      0.294     0.385
Transportation  0.485     0.085     0.234

Comment: @AdamO I edited the question title. The first sentence is one the assumptions of pca. 
This assumption encompasses the belief
that the data has a high SNR. Hence, principal
components with larger associated variances
represent interesting dynamics, while
those with lower variances represent noise.

Comment: @user3086871 I don't understand your reply to ttnphns. What are the numbers that you wrote there? What does `Housing 0.444 0.020 0.204` etc. mean?

Comment: @amoeba I have edited the question details, please check if it helps

Comment: Not really. The maximum variance for these four variables is given by PCA on this subset of variables, as @ttnphns suggested. It seems that instead you want to make all four loadings high, but this is too vague a constraint. You need to think how you want to formalize your problem. Currently it's unanswerable I am afraid.